# Can't get value in dim with CInt vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm fairly new to vb.net and can't find why this is not working, dim test is just empty after this line happened. Any possible problems?

```
Dim test As Integer = CInt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TermstextFieldTypeId"))
```

Comment: Since an Integer cannot be "empty", your question currently does not make sense. Can you provide a [mcve]? Your code line looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code;

If your `TermstextFieldTypeId` setting `IsNullOrEmpty` then get default(0) value else getter setting value.

```
Dim val = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TermstextFieldTypeId")
Dim test As Integer = CInt(IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(val), 0, val))
```

Comment: I suspect this will be no different to what they already have. The default value for `Integer` is 0 anyway

Comment: No, If TermstextFieldTypeId is null or empty then it will throw "Input string was not in a correct format." exception.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't use `Integer.TryParse`?  It's possible for a non-empty string to still be something that isn't a number.  Also, I'd prefer `If `to `IIf`, since `IIf` is a function that will evaluate all its arguments (not such an issue here, but can be in other settings) whereas `If` is a built-in operator.